# How to include a given named group in a .NET regex multiple times without copy-paste?

Tags: .net, regex

I have a complex regex, which contains constructs like this one:

```
"(" + sectionPattern + separatorPattern + ")*" + sectionPattern
```

The `sectionPattern` is a named group of complicated internal structure. Since `sectionPattern` appears twice, the long string defining this named group will be copied twice into the regex pattern. Moreover, because there is another, similar substructure inside `sectionPattern`, it will be copy-pasted four times, and so on. I couldn't find a way to avoid such duplication, and the whole pattern is 4389 characters long now. It works, but I would prefer it being much-much shorter.

I thought there is a way to refer to an already defined named group in other parts of the pattern using only its name. I mean if you have a named group like this:

```
(?<sectionPattern>some_very_long_and_complicated_pattern)
```

...then you could refer briefly to it in other parts of the pattern like this:

```
(?<sectionPattern>)
```

I tried to use a "named backreference":

```
\k<sectionPattern>
```

...but this matches only when the second match contains exactly the same text as the first one. Any solutions?

Comment: No, this is not possible. What exactly is wrong with your first piece of code?

Comment: Sounds like you want a lexer.

Comment: @NullUserExceptionఠ_ఠ It works, I just don't like copy-pasted code. Even CSS has now variables to avoid, for example, copying the same RGB code multiple times. With named groups you practically define "regex pattern variables", and I don't understand why one is forced to "redeclare" it again and again...

Comment: @kol Because that's not the intended use of named capture groups. They are meant to replace numbered capture groups for clarity.

Comment: I think the "combinatorial explosion" is caused by the hierarchical structure of the pattern. Maybe I could subdivide the string with a high-level pattern into sections first, then apply a lower-level pattern to each section, and so on. Or, as @leppie says, I could abandon feeding my regex, and start using flex+bison or GOLD Parser instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to create a "reusable" pattern.  You must repeat the pattern everywhere it's needed.

However, here's a better (more readable) way to compose those patterns:

```
var pattern = string.Format("({0}{1})*{0}", sectionPattern, separatorPattern);
```

Comment: I assembled the regex using variables for its parts and combining them this way, using string.Format(). The problem is not that I copy-pasted my pattern strings, because I did not. The problem is that the resulting pattern looks like as if it was created by a copy-paste method...

Comment: @kol There's no way around that, unfortunately.